# How to set variable to decimal fraction by parseFloat?

Tags: javascript

I have troubles with my first script. When I manually change `mp` to `1.5` in script, then it works and `bet = 15`. But when I click button with function `changemp`, write `1.5` and click ok, it multiplies bet by `1`, not by `1.5`. (It's not full script, just a few lines of it :D )

```
var bet = 10
var mp = 2

... a few lines later

if(thenumber > rollUnder)
{
    start = start * mp
}

function changemp() {
  mp = parseInt(prompt("Please enter the new multiplier", mp));
}
```

Comment: Need to use parseFloat like your question title said (you have parseInt) and the code above will not change because the code already ran... And no one really cares about your age, leave that out of the questions in the future. ;)

Comment: `parseInt` will only return whole numbers.  Try `parseFloat` instead.

Comment: Nice you start to learn programming. As good practice. close your lines with a semicolon `;` by default.

Comment: @epascarello, true about the age line, but as a teacher I kind of liked it. It takes courage to ask things! Makes you think twice about the tone of your answer/comment.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I've already tried using parseFlat instead of parseInt, but same result.

Comment: Also when you use `parseInt` for integers it's common practice to specify the `base`, which in most cases would be base `10`: `parseInt(«string», «radix»)`

Comment: are you using a comma `,` or point `.` as decimal sign?

Comment: @Mouser is it so common? I always thought that, since it's the default, it's pretty clear without the base (which, imho, just clutters the code)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: at `MDN` and I agree *An integer between 2 and 36 that represents the radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems) of the above mentioned string. Specify 10 for the decimal numeral system commonly used by humans. Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified, usually defaulting the value to 10.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wasn't going to post an answer, but because this is more or less becoming a tutorial experience I will:

JavaScript is weakly typed. It can convert different types without you needing to cast. If at runtime it succeeds wonderful, if not fail.

the function `prompt` returns a string value. You want to make sure that the value used in your application is a `float` or `integer`. Both are of the object type `number` in JavaScript, so not a `string`. `parseFloat` and `parseInt` are used to convert string values to a number. They have drawbacks. They only convert number values at the beginning of the string (or more correct, truncate the rest of the string).

Look:

```js
var string1 = "test string 1";
var string2 = "1 test string";

console.log(parseInt(string1, 10)); //NaN
console.log(parseInt(string2, 10)); //1
```

Same for `parseFloat`.

The difference between `parseFloat` and `parseInt` is the type they return: the former returns a float (floating point number - decimal) and the latter returns an integer. Your multiplier allows for integers. `.` is used in JavaScript as the decimal sign!

We can see the differences:

```js
var a = "1.5";
var b = "1,5";

console.log(parseFloat(a)); //1.5
console.log(parseFloat(b)); //1 //ignores the comma - truncates after 1
```

Last is the wrapper function `Number` to create a new number:

```js
var string1 = "test string 1.5";
var string2 = "1.5 test string";
var string3 = "1.5";

console.log(Number(string1)); //NaN
console.log(Number(string2)); //NaN
console.log(Number(string3)); //1.5
```

`Number` can't strip values from a string containing other characters then allowed for a number. So it does string to number conversion, but not like `parseFloat` and `parseInt`

Now your script:

```js
var bet, mp, start;
bet = 10;
mp = changemp();

start = bet * mp;

function changemp() {
  //we are using return here:
  //use parseFloat and trim() to remove unwanted white space characters
  return parseFloat(prompt("Please enter the new multiplier", 2).trim() );
}

console.log(start);
```

On a last note: `prompt` is basic, good for learning the language but as you have seen not the best fit for these kind of operations. A better implementation would be using the `input` element with the `number` type (common in modern browsers)

```js
var multiplierInput, calculateButton, resultSpan;
multiplierInput = document.getElementById("multiplier");
calculateButton = document.getElementById("calculate");
resultSpan = document.getElementById("result");

//assign event:
calculateButton.addEventListener("click", calculate);

function calculate() {
  resultSpan.textContent = parseFloat(multiplierInput.value) * 10;
}
```

```html
10 x <input type="number" id="multiplier" /> = <span id="result"></span><br />
<button id="calculate">calculate</button>
```

Comment: Wow! +rep for you. I know I probably made more wrond decisions when writing script. It's hard to make everything right when you are learning a language about 1-2 week. And btw. I didn't write this script from 1st line, I was inspired by another script, that has less functions than my.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using `parseInt` and the integer number in 1.5 is 1. Just don't use `parseInt` in the and changemp() function and will works like you want it.

You may to use `parseFloat` too. But `parseFloat` will set a lot of decimals when you do advanced calculates.

Comment: Really, check using number() function instead of parseFloat or parseInt.  And check if in somewhere mp is changing between int to string.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have used parseInt instead of praseFloat function.

parseInt will only return integer if we pass decimal values then it will return the ceiling values

use parseFloat if your number can be in decimal places too.

```
function changemp() {
  mp = parseFloat(prompt("Please enter the new multiplier", mp));
}
```

Comment: share your complete code, the error may be coming from somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Um... It's strange, but when I removed the parseInt or parseFloat (

```
function changemp() {
mp = prompt("Please enter the new multiplier", mp);
}
```

It looks like it's working :) But thanks guys so much for help, every lore is helpful.

Comment: Ask yourself why you use `parseFloat` in this case. Prompt returns a string and you want to make sure you use a float or integer. Your solution works because JavaScript is weakly typed and automatically converts the string value into a float. If you did this in `C` or another strong typed language it would fail.